# How to update a single key value in an array inside for loop using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to update each field in the flags[ ] array inside a for loop. during every iteration i need to update the respective flag to true. Please help me to solve this.

```
var flags = {terminationFlag : false,
        transferFlag : false,
        jrCancelledFlag : false,
        jrFilledFlag : false,
        jrOpenFlag : false,
        miegFlags : false,
        headcountFlag : false,
        replacementReqFlag : false,
        costcentreFlag : false,
        gradeMapFlag : false}


var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (i=0; i < array.length ;i++){
flags[i] = true
}

if (("terminationFlag" = true) && ("transferFlag" = true)){
 //do some operation
 }
```

Comment: Why aren't you iterating on the keys instead of unrelated indices?

Answer (score 1):

You have a flags object which is not an array. You can use Object.keys if you want an array

```js
let flags = {
  terminationFlag: false,
  transferFlag: false,
  jrCancelledFlag: false,
  jrFilledFlag: false,
  jrOpenFlag: false,
  miegFlags: false,
  headcountFlag: false,
  replacementReqFlag: false,
  costcentreFlag: false,
  gradeMapFlag: false
}

Object.keys(flags).forEach(key => {
  flags[key] = true;
})
console.log(flags)
```

PS: `if (("terminationFlag" = true) && ("transferFlag" = true)){`

will not work as expected since you try to set a string to true in the if statement instead of testing them

`if (flags["terminationFlag"] && flags["transferFlag"]) {` or

`if (flags["terminationFlag"]===true && flags["transferFlag"]===true) {`

Answer (score 1):

The traditional `for` loop in your code is used to iterate over elements in an array, not the key-value pairs in the provided `flags` object.

Instead use a `for...in` statement to iterate over the keys in the `flags` object and set the values of the keys to `true`.

Try this out:

```
var flags = {terminationFlag : false,
    transferFlag : false,
    jrCancelledFlag : false,
    jrFilledFlag : false,
    jrOpenFlag : false,
    miegFlags : false,
    headcountFlag : false,
    replacementReqFlag : false,
    costcentreFlag : false,
    gradeMapFlag : false}

// a little more readable than the previous answers
for (const prop in flags) {
  flags[prop] = true;
}

console.log(flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

`flags` is an `Object`. So, you can use `Object.key()` to iterate keys and assign values.

```
'use strict';

var flags = {
  terminationFlag: false,
  transferFlag: false,
  jrCancelledFlag: false,
  jrFilledFlag: false,
  jrOpenFlag: false,
  miegFlags: false,
  headcountFlag: false,
  replacementReqFlag: false,
  costcentreFlag: false,
  gradeMapFlag: false
};

for (let attr of Object.keys(flags)) {
  flags[attr] = true;
}
```

Also,

> if (("terminationFlag" = true) && ("transferFlag" = true)){

You're using `=` which means assignment. You need to use `====` to check condition. And, since we know the key whose value we need to check, we can check using truthy check.

```
if (flags.terminationFlag && flags.transferFlag) {
  //do some operation
}
```